# Hausman and Lagrange Multiplier test in plm - to use or not to use?

Tags: r, panel-data, economics, plm

Following on a previous thread regarding the Hausman test ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989925/hausman-type-test-in-r)) in which the reference unfortunately disappeared @briatte , I am faced with some additional Hausman related questions. While the previous thread alluded to the fact that the taking of the absolute value might be a problem in the Hausman execution, I am wondering whether the problems I am having are caused by this indeed.

Depending on the `random.method` specification I use, the results can be dramatically different, which makes me wonder which ones to trust (maybe none).

In the following 'vit' represents a formula with on the right side only variables that vary both over time and over individuals, while full represents the same variables + Year fixed effect dummies + some variables that differ for every year but are the same for every firm (firm fixed effects).

Here are some results

```
phtest(vit,data = p.data, effect="twoways", random.method="amemiya")

    Hausman Test

data:  vit
chisq = 13.0489, df = 30, p-value = 0.9969
alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

Versus

```
phtest(vit,data = p.data, effect="twoways", random.method="walhus")

    Hausman Test

data:  vit
chisq = 76.3063, df = 30, p-value = 6.617e-06
alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

While it is of course possible to get different results with different tests, the radical difference here makes me wonder...

A similar situation occurs with the LM tests:

```
plmtest(full, data=p.data, effect="twoways",type="kw")

    Lagrange Multiplier Test - two-ways effects (King and Wu)

data:  full
normal = -2.3819, df = 2, p-value = 0.01722
alternative hypothesis: significant effects
```

versus

```
plmtest(full, data=p.data, effect="twoways",type="ghm")

    Lagrange Multiplier Test - two-ways effects (Gourieroux, Holly and Monfort)

data:  full
chisq = 0.0025, df = 2, p-value = 0.9987
alternative hypothesis: significant effects
```

Can anyone make a suggestion on what to do?

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: 1) Do the estimated RE models which you input to `phtest` differ substantially? 2) `ghm` and `kw` are different tests [but a bit related depending on the through the honda statistic], but run on the same model.